# How to update a dataframe with a user defined function (pandas python)

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

Image for the code:-

[image]

I m struggling updating the original dataframe when using a user defined function for running a task:

```
def filter_rows(df,col,string):

       df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
       df = df[~df[col].str.contains(string)]
       return df
```

When i run the above function on `df1`, it does return a trimmed down version. But that version is not updated in main `df1`.

```
 filter_rows(df1,'smoking_status','never smoked')
```

Meaning if i view `df1` seperatly in the next cell, I still see the complete non trimmed dataset.

I've used `inplace=True` where possible but I cant seem to find a way to do that here.

Need a solution that could be used in other situations aswell.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reassigning `df` inside function changes reference to that object. To understand better about pass by reference refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/4755194).

To filter df without reassigning you can use `df.drop`

```
df.drop(df[df[col].str.contains(string)].index, inplace = True)
```

So your final function would be

```
def filter_rows(df,col,string):

       df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
       df.drop(df[df[col].str.contains(string)].index, inplace = True)
       return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the dataframe the function returns back to the original dataframe.

```
df1 = filter_rows(df1,'smoking_status','never smoked')
```

Comment: I need to make these functions into a class. So not ideal. Looking for an in-function solution. Thanks though