# How to update pyspark dataframe inside a Python function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a Python function that receives a pyspark dataframe and checks if it has all the columns expected by other functions used in a script. In particular, if the column `'weight'` is missing, I want to update the dataframe passed by the user by assigning a new column to it.

For example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def verify_cols(df):
    if 'weight' not in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumn('weight', F.lit(1))  # Can I update `df` inside this function?
```

As you can see, I want the function to update `df`. How can I achieve this? If possible, I would like to avoid using a `return` statement.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744816/how-to-update-a-dataframe-with-a-user-defined-function-pandas-python) is very similar but uses pandas' `inplace` argument.

Comment: `verify_cols` is not an [UDF](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/) but a plain Python function, so your code should run without problems. You can simply return `df` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the return statement you can declare a class and keep the df as a member field.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.DataFrame import DataFrame
class Validator:
    def __init__(self, df: DataFrame):
        self.df = df

    def verify_cols(self):
        if 'weight' not in self.df.columns:
            self.df = self.df.withColumn('weight', F.lit(1))
```

After calling verify_cols methods, the field df will be updated.